# How to get homepage to swap language?

Tags: transcribe

For some reason having difficulty getting the homepage to translate. It just won't swap language although it adds the language prefix after the domain name "domain.co.uk/cy/ but the language switcher links still show's "en" and no content gets translated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had caching set on the homepage. Turning this off sorted it.